# xml access contain

Tags: xml, data-access-layer

I have one xml structure file which is arranged like

```
<AllReport>
    <Report>
            <DataPoint1>
            </DataPoint1>
            <DataPoint2>
            </DataPoint2> 
            <DataPoint3>
            </DataPoint3>     
    </Report>
    <Report>
            <DataPoint1>
            </DataPoint1>
            <DataPoint2>
            </DataPoint2> 
            <DataPoint3>
            </DataPoint3> 
    </Report>
     so on so forth....
</AllReport>
```

Is there any better way to access DataPoint1 directly without using multi fat for loop?

Comment: In which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use LINQ to XML

```
 var xmlItems = XDocument.Load("yourXML);
 var result = from e in xmlItems.Descendants("Report").Descendants("DataPoint1");

foreach(item in result ){

  //it goes though all DataPoint 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expressions `/AllReport/Report/DataPoint1` and `//DataPoint1` will both return a list of all the `DataPoint1` nodes in your sample document.  You can then iterate over that list using whatever means your DOM library or chosen language provides you.

Which you use would depend on the nature of the actual document.  If every instance of `DataPoint1` that you wish to access is nested in the same way, then use the former.  If you cannot be sure of the nesting of `DataPoint1` (perhaps some reports have subreports, or there is a "summary" `DataPoint1` child of `AllReport`, then the latter may be preferable.

It is normally best to choose a more precise expression, both for performance and error-detection reasons.